# Adding a script in a C++ application

Tags: c++, python, vba, embedding

I'm working on a project simulating a stock market. People buy and sell a stock and I would like to call each turn a script to try a strategy against the market.

What I want is a function in C++ which send an vector of integer as argument to a vba or python script which return an array of 3 integers.

I've searched for a solution but all i could find is a way to execute a script in python, but I don't know how I can send and get an argument from this script.
I think my problem is common but i don't know where to head to find a solution.

Thank you!

(I'm not a native english speaker so sorry if I made grammar error)

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz IIRC it's not been called that in years - it's `Boost.Python` now...

Comment: Getting back a vector from another process will require some sort of IPC (Inter Process Communication) which is generally platform specific, so you need to specify which operating system.  However, it might be better to write the whole lot in just one language and program.

Comment: @cdarke It's designed to work on windows 7 but I can use a traditionnal array instead of a vector

Comment: If you are not bound to python or vba, those things are fairly easy with lua or chaiscript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On windows you use the function [`CreateProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425.aspx) to start another program. Use the full path of the python interpreter as the first argument. Start the second argument with the path to the python script.

If you can fit a string representing your vector in 32768 characters, you can supply the vector in the second argument to CreateProcess.

A more flexible option is create a child process with redirected in- and output, as shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). You can then write the vector to the standard input of the python process and read the answer back from its standard output.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this.

The way I would do it is to [popen()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) your "script" [which would be something like "python myscript.py -arg1 -arg2"]. Depending on how large your vector is, you could either store it in a file or pass it as part of the arguments [there is a limit in Windows of something like 8KB for the argument string].

The output would then appear as the result from popen()'s pipe.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Boost.Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/python/doc/). It will help you to embed python in your app.